# Why does $V_{1,-1}V^{-1}_{-1,-1}V_{-1,1}=\sigma_1^2R_1^2$? (Covariance Matrix Property)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, covariance-matrix

I'm told that $V_{1,-1}V^{-1}_{-1,-1}V_{-1,1}=\sigma_1^2R_1^2$ but I'm having a hard time seeing it. If I understand correctly, I can see that $V_{1,-1}V^{-1}_{-1,-1} = b_{-1}^T$ but I don't see the former.

Understanding the notation: $V$ is the covariance matrix. The part of the matrix being specified is denoted by the subscripts. A positive number means that it includes that row (if it's the first number) or column (if that's the second number). A negative number means it includes all rows/columns except for that number. Thus $V_{1,-1}$ is the first row excluding the first element, V_{-1,1} excludes the first element of the first column, and $V^{-1}_{-1,-1}$ is the portion of the inverse covariance matrix that excludes the first row and column.

I'm using a couple resources that use slightly different notation. It's probably easiest to become familiar with the problem by pulling up [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/117426?seq=5#metadata_info_tab_contents) article. The paragraph after equation (4) on page 1823 claims the result but I'd love some help seeing it and building some intuition

---

Some Working Knowledge:

$\beta = \frac{\sigma_{12}}{\sigma_1^2} = \frac{\sigma_{12}}{\sigma_1^2}\frac{\sigma_{2}}{\sigma_2} = \frac{\sigma_{12}}{\sigma_1\sigma_2}\frac{\sigma_{2}}{\sigma_1} = \rho \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}$

Another fact I'm aware of (although I'm not sure how to show it) is $\rho_{\hat y,y}^2 = R^2$.

Comment: Is it $R_1^2$ or $1-R_1^2$?

Comment: Are you trying to describe the situation at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140080?

Comment: @papgeo Well if you have  $V_1,1 - V_{1,-1} V_{-1,-1}^{-1} V_{-1,1}$ then it becomes $\sigma_1^2(1-R^2_{1})$ so that implies what I have written. No?

Comment: @whuber if it is the same question then I may need help understanding how regression coefficients, correlations, and $R^2$ are so interconnected. I know a mathematical definition for each but it's not obvious to me how partial correlations relate to $\sigma^2R^2$ and how $b$ relates to correlation...  I'll edit my question to highlight a bit more where I'm at

Comment: The conditional variance of the first variable given all others is $\sigma^2_c = V_1 - V_{1,-1}V^{-1}_{-1,-1}V_{-1,1}$, where $V_1$ is the total variance and $\sigma^2_c$ is the unexplained variance. Hence, rearranging that equation, $V_1 - \sigma^2_c = V_{1,-1}V^{-1}_{-1,-1}V_{-1,1}$, but the right side $V_1 - \sigma^2_c = V_1 (1 - \sigma^2_c/V_1) = V_1 (1-R^2)$.

Comment: @papgeo I think the last part for me to understand is why $\sigma_c^2$ is to understand why $V_{1,-1}V^{-1}_{-1,-1}V_{-1,1}$ is the explained variation is $V_{1,1}$ and then I'll be golden. Could you help me see that?